# fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: Invalid argument

Tags: git, cygwin

Upon doing

git add .

I get the following message -

```
fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: Invalid argument
```

I am using git on cygwin on Windows 7

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. It's [fixed in git 1.7.1.1 and later](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=365).